# Creation of new Xtext Project gives an error out-of-the-box in Eclipse DSL tools

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext, eclipse-emf, ecore

I have downloaded Eclipse DSL Tools, Neon.2 version. And I create new Xtext Project.

[image: New Xtext Project]

I click finish and I get bunch of projects in my workspace:

[image]

However, I have an error out of the box with GenerateL.mwe2 file:

[image]

Error:

```
A value of type 'org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator' can not be assigned to the feature org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.addComponent(org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.IWorkflowComponent)
```

Also there is an error in `build.properties` files saying this:

```
Bundle org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils cannot be resolved
```

Here is the file:

```
source.. = src/,\
           src-gen/,\
           xtend-gen/
bin.includes = .,\
               META-INF/,\
               plugin.xml
additional.bundles = org.eclipse.xtext.xbase,\
                     org.eclipse.xtext.common.types,\
                     org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator,\
                     org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,\
                     org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils,\
                     org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch,\
                     org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib,\
                     org.objectweb.asm,\
                     org.apache.commons.logging,\
                     org.apache.log4j,\
                     com.ibm.icu
```

How do I solve these errors?

Comment: It looks like you somehow managed not to install new

Comment: Actually I meant Mwe

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I should mention I did create a project without errors first time and started new eclipse instance in which I wrote `Hello Lazar!`, everything worked fine. Afterwards  I deleted everything (since I created it on desktop only to see if everything was installed) and created new project in different workspace. From that moment and onward, I can't create a xtext project without error.

Comment: Hmmm maybe your install did somehow get broken did you check the target platform in the eclipse preferences

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Where exactly  do I look for that?

Comment: Window preferences search for target platform

Comment: It has only **Running Platform (Active)** in target definitions and at the bottom of the window, there is Locations label where says: **$(eclipse_home) - C:\Program Files\dsl-neon\eclipse 806 plugins available**

Comment: Can you hit the reload button there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133911/discussion-between-clzola-and-christian-dietrich).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your target platform is correctly loaded and contains the missing plugins `Window -> Preferences -> Search for Target platform`. Use Reload and Edit buttons to make sure it's refreshed and to inspect the contents. If it is still missing you may need to reinstall the dependencies

Comment: I needed to reinstall eclipse.